# Way to enable Quick Open search box in Command Center

Tags: visual-studio-code

I downloaded the latest version (1.75.1) of Visual Studio Code.
Enabled Command Center by setting **window.commandCenter** option to true.
After that I disabled Quick Open search box by right clicking and unchecking **hide quick open** option.
Couldn't find any direct method to turn it back on.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click the "go back" or "go forward" buttons and click the entry that says "quick open" in the right click menu that pops up. That will cause the quick open input to be shown again, and if you right click again, you'll see that same entry with a check mark beside it to indicate that it is shown.

In fact, the "hide <X>" entry that appears at the top of the menu is just a shortcut to clicking the entry below it for that specific input of the command center.

The handy thing is that VS Code will prevent you from hiding all three of the "go back", "go foward", and "quick open" inputs of the command center, so you always have some part of the command center visible, and something you can right click on to get that popup menu.

Answer (score 0):

At the top bar of the window, **right click** on any arrow of the command center.

[image]

And enable Quick Open:

[image]